# Jenkins shell command unexpected truncation / EOF

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a Makefile in my project root folder. Among other commands is:

```
export DOCKER_REPO?=myRepo
export APP_NAME?=myApp
export VAR1?=foo
export VAR2?=bar

TAG?=$(shell git rev-list HEAD --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit)

pack: ## creates the docker image
    docker build . -f ./build/Dockerfile \
    --platform linux/amd64 \
    --build-arg VAR1=$(VAR1) \
    --build-arg VAR2=$(VAR2) \
    -t $(DOCKER_REPO)/$(APP_NAME):$(TAG) \
    -t $(DOCKER_REPO)/$(APP_NAME):latest
```

When I `make pack` from a local machine, the command works fine.

When Jenkins executes it as part of a pipeline...

```
steps {
   script {
      sh "make pack"
      // other stuff 
   }
}
```

... string vars are interpolated except for the last line!

The resulting command that's executed:

```
docker build . -f ./build/Dockerfile \
    --platform linux/amd64 \
    --build-arg VAR1=foo \
    --build-arg VAR2=bar \
    -t myRepo/myApp:8a49356
```

It misses `-t myRepo/myApp:latest` completely.

I cannot figure it out. Should I escape/sanitize my `TAG` var somehow?

Comment: What happens if you add an empty line at the end of your makefile?

Comment: Also check that you don't have a space after the backslash in the but-last line.

Comment: @user1934428 tried both things. I do have a newline at the bottom of Makefile and no trailing whitespaces in any lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `TAG` comes from

```
env.TAG = sh(script: "git rev-list HEAD --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit", returnStdout: true)
```

Appending a `.trim()` fixed my issue.